# Separation of footnote numbers when I convert my Word document to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

When I convert my Word document to PDF, the number of footnotes that are higher than 10, get separated from each other. I attached a photo of an example of my problem.

[image: The example of my problem]

before converting:

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot from word showing non-printing characters too? (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c2d8a607-5646-4165-8b08-bd68f9d172a0) Also, how exactly do you convert them to pdf? Have you tried another method? Which version of Word do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I've used 2 method for converting:1) save as --> choose .pdf format  2) by using save as Adobe pdf option.
I use word 2016.
I attached the screenshot of my word to my question.

Comment: is it a footnote created automatically by word (using insert - footnote option), or manually by you? Could you please do the original screenshot with non-printing characters visible?

Comment: The footnotes created automatically by word. I attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your file with Adobe Reader.
Open The PDF file with Adobe Reader.
Then click

> Edit -> Edit Text & Images

in the menu bar
AND drag each digit and drop it in its proper place
OR select digit(s) and use <kbd>UP</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd><kbd>LEFT</kbd><kbd>RIGHT</kbd> keys to put it in the proper place.

Then *Drag and Drop* each digit. It's simple.
P.S.: My Adobe Reader version is 2015 DC.